# How do I work with nested vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to work with vectors of vectors of ints for a sudoku puzzle solver I'm writing.

**Question 1:**

If I'm going to access a my 2d vector by index, do I have to initialize it with the appropriate size first?

For example:

```
typedef vector<vector<int> > array2d_t;

void readAPuzzle(array2d_t grid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            cin >> grid[i][j];
    return;
}

int main()
{
    array2d_t grid;
    readAPuzzle(grid);
}
```

Will seg fault.  I assume this is because it is trying to access elments of grid that have not yet been initialized?

I've swapped out grid's declaration line with:

```
array2d_t grid(9, vector<int>(9, 0));
```

And this seems to get rid of this seg fault.  Is this the right way to handle it?

**Question 2:**

Why is it that when I try to read into my grid from cin, and then print out the grid, the grid is blank?

I'm using the following code to do so:

```
void printGrid(array2d_t grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j] + " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void readAPuzzle(array2d_t grid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            cin >> grid[i][j];

    return;
}

int main()
{
    array2d_t grid(9, vector<int>(9, 0));
    printGrid(grid);
    readAPuzzle(grid);
    printGrid(grid);
}
```

And I attempt to run my program like:

```
./a.out < sudoku-test
```

Where sudoku-test is a file containing the following:

```
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
5 8 4 0 0 2 0 3 0  
0 6 0 8 3 0 0 7 5  
0 4 1 0 0 6 0 0 0  
7 9 0 0 2 0 0 5 1  
0 0 0 9 0 0 6 8 0  
9 3 0 0 1 5 0 4 0  
0 2 0 4 0 0 5 1 8  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6
```

The first call to printGrid() gives a blank grid, when instead I should be seeing a 9x9 grid of 0's since that is how I initialized it.  The second call should contain the grid above.  However, both times it is blank.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: checkout boost.multi_array if you want easier way to deal with dynamic multidimensional data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1: Yes, that is the correct way to handle it. However, notice that nested vectors are a rather inefficient way to implement a 2D array. One vector and calculating indices by `x + y * width` is usually a better option.

Q2A: Calculating `grid[i][j] + " "` does not concatenate two strings (because the left hand side is int, not a string) but instead adds the numeric value to a pointer (the memory address of the first character of the string " "). Use `cout << grid[i][j] << " "` instead.

Q2B: You are passing the array by value (it gets copied) for `readAPuzzle`. The the function reads into its local copy, which gets destroyed when the function returns. Pass by reference instead (this avoids making a copy and uses the original instead):

```
void readAPuzzle(array2d_t& grid)
```

Comment: @Tronic, ah I see. I thought the default behavior for vectors would be to pass by reference, like arrays do.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the first printGrid() doesn't give me a 9x9 grid of 0's though?  If it is copied, the zero's should still be present when printing.

Comment: Arrays are a strange special case. I wouldn't say that arrays are passed by reference, but rather that when you write [], you actually get a pointer (that is then passed by value). It is a matter of perspective, though.

Comment: Replace `cout << grid[i][j] + " ";` with `cout << grid[i][j] << " ";`

Comment: Added Q2A, which answers to the first half of Q2. String concatenation by + only works when at least one of the sides is std::string, and the other is either C string or another std::string.

Comment: Btw, does anyone else find it a shameful that STL doesn't provide any 2D containers? Such things would be highly useful.

Comment: @Tronic, in your single dimension vector, for calculating the index, what does width represent?